# Expresso Store: Return page from payment gateway error: form has expired

Tags: expresso-store

I'm using a custom gateway (offsite) for exp-resso store; upon successful transaction the return page gives out "This form has expired. Please refresh and try again."

The transaction is captured albeit not completed.

I'm using the default store_example templates.

Edit: EE ver 2.9.3; Exp-resso 2.5.0

Comment: I would like to add that the response from the payment gateway is POST method.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the "return" parameter?

```
{exp:store:checkout return="order/ORDER_HASH"}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Place Order" />
{/exp:store:checkout}
```

Comment: Yes. This is the code that i used:{exp:store:checkout
    form_class="form-horizontal"
    return="store_example/order/ORDER_HASH"
    error_handling="inline"
    error_delimiters='<span class="help-inline">|</span>'}

Comment: And what's the URI you get directed to?