# Expresso Store v2.5.1 and EE v2.8.1, WorldPay doesn't redirect after successful order?

Tags: expresso-store, payment-gateway, worldpay

For some reason after a successful test order I am not being redirected back to the site after paying via WorldPay.

I have made sure that the settings tally up and are correct as per the docs here: https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/payment_gateways.html#worldpay

I have also checked the return URL is correct and even tried making it an absolute link, but again no luck.

I have also tried disabling secure forms via the config file using the below as v2.8.1 doesn't have the option to turn off secure forms now:
$config['disable_csrf_protection'] = 'y';

The orders are successful as I can see them in the CP afterwards, it also works when registering a new member, but again doesn't redirect.

Another small issue I have, which may or may not be related, is the Freemember logout link gives an error regarding not being authorized, see below:
"You are not authorized to perform this action"

Any ideas before I resort to trying an EE upgrade to v2.9.3 would be helpful please? Ideally I'd rather not have to update it at this time.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Latest update

After updating EE to v2.10.2 the issue is still present (no redirection after payment at WP TEST server), orders go through successfully and are added to the CP as status 'new'.

I am now receiving error emails from WP to see what's happening, I get the following:

Error reported: Callback to http://www.example.com/?ACT=39&H=9daf75637f356b4deff064a7aa93333e: NOT OK, recevied HTTP status: 302

And the response attachement shows the following:

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 01 Feb 2016 11:03:37 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
Set-Cookie: exp_last_visit=1138964616; expires=Tue, 31-Jan-2017 11:03:36 GMT; path=/; httponly
Set-Cookie: exp_last_activity=1454324616; expires=Tue, 31-Jan-2017 11:03:36 GMT; path=/; httponly
Set-Cookie: exp_csrf_token=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; httponly
Set-Cookie: exp_csrf_token=1afab38559e3fdd5f89351e6bae32f562a49b981; expires=Mon, 01-Feb-2016 13:03:36 GMT; path=/; httponly
Location: http://www.example.com/shop/order/2defc3fdfcc028fc36a4c1b3e3607ec9
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
MS-Author-Via: DAV

I'm not sure what any of this means as I haven't experienced this type of issue/error before.

Any ideas please anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that trying to use radio buttons to choose a payment method was the cause of the issue here, which I'm still not 100% sure why. I was allowing a choice bewteen 'Manual' for invoice based payment and 'WorldPay' for online payment.

So changing over to the default method of using the select box field, as below, seemed to make the difference:

{payment_method_options}

The checkout process now works fine, phew!

Comment: Good you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

WorldPay's hosted payment confirmation pages (successful or unsuccessful) won't automatically redirect back to the EE Store order confirmation page under your own domain, if the callback (Payment Response) is unsuccessful.

If your orders are appearing as Order Status *New* in *EE : Store : Orders*, the callback should be working OK, but if they're marked *Incomplete*, the callback is failing ([a problem I had](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/35369/expresso-store-callback-from-worldpay-returning-403-forbidden)).  WorldPay's CP can be configured for an error email to be sent in this case: *Payment Response failure email address*.  See [WorldPay documentation](http://support.worldpay.com/support/kb/bg/paymentresponse/pr0000.html).

In the past for another shopping cart, I've needed to hardcode into WorldPay's *ResultY.html* and *ResultC.html* files a return link variable, either as a meta refresh tag or anchor.  I don't know if this is required in this case.

Here are the WorldPay settings that work for me:

- Payment Response URL: `<wpdisplay item=MC_callback>`
- Payment Response enabled? *tick*
- Shopper Redirect URL *(blank)*
- Shopper Redirect button enabled? *(blank)*
- Enable Recurring Payment Response *(blank)*
- Enable the Shopper Response: *tick*
- Suspension of Payment Response *(blank)*
- Payment Response failure email address: *(your email)*
- Attach HTTP(s) Payment Message to the failure email? *tick*
- Merchant receipt email address: *(blank)*
- Enable Mobile Pages?  *(blank)*
- No Worldpay Header enabled?       *(blank)*
- Remove Breadcrumb?    *(blank)*
- Info servlet password *(blank)*
- Payment Response password: *enter and confirm pwd also in Store settings*
- MD5 secret for transactions: *enter and confirm pwd also in Store settings*
- SignatureFields: *(blank)*

Comment: Thanks Kenny, the orders are in fact appearing correctly in the CP, WorldPay just doesn't seem to acknowledge the redirect code though. It's setup the same way as another site I have built using Store and WorldPay (which works fine), so it's a strange one! At the moment, all I can think is that it's something to do with the version of either Store or EE, but it would be good if I can confirm that before I start updating EE.

Comment: I've just successfuly configured [Worldpay with Store v2.5.1 and EE v2.10.2](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/35369/expresso-store-callback-from-worldpay-returning-403-forbidden) after an upgrade of Store.  WorldPay does in fact redirect correctly back to the EE order confirmation page without additional configuration.  CSRF Protection was off by default in the 2.10.2 config.php.  Have you [configured an encryption key](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/installation.html)?

Comment: Glad you have resolved your issue. I'm going to try an upgrade to EE v2.9.3 tomorrow morning if I haven't had a reply from DevDemon before then. Yes I have an encryption hey setup along with CSRF disabled, but still the problem persists.

Comment: Have added my working WorldPay settings for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the info Kenny. Busy morning upgrading from EE v2.8.1 to v2.9.3 to v2.10.2, but still no luck. It's now worse than it was, as the order now doesn't go through, they are marked as 'incomplete' in the CP even though WP sends out a confirmation of payment email but still no redirect. 
I did notice that you seem to have more options/settings from within WP, I have the necessary ones according to the Store docs but curious as to why it's different.
Back to the drwaing board now though as after a whole morning of upgrading I'm worse off than before!

Comment: After talking to WP, it would seem that they are experiencing some issues their end to do with callbacks on the TEST server. Once they let me know it's fixed, I'll be able fully test again...

Comment: Are you getting the callback failure emails from WP with attached request and response text files?  Is there an HTTP error in the response?  I tested on Production once it was activated, to avoid any test server factor.

Comment: Perhaps there's an alternative gateway in action here...?
https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-worldpay/issues/3

Comment: Just added some more info in the original question, I get callback errors as above!